# Pass data from RecyclerView in Fragment to another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have application with `RecycleView` and after click on row I need open another `RecycleView` in another `Fragment` based on data which was in clicked row in first RecycleView. I had application where it was working, and now I want `DrawerMenu` and `Fragments`, and I don't know how to do it. I'm newbie on Android and all what I know is from tutorials.

**BaseActivity**

```
package cz.revelio.mhdapp;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new ZapisFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_message);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.nav_chat:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ZapFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new SeznamFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_message:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ZapisFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_share:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_send:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

From `BaseActivity` I can call **SeznamFragment** where is first `RecyclerView`:

```
   package cz.revelio.mhdapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;


public class SeznamFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    TextView info;
    Context context;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_seznam, container, false);
    info = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_count_in_dash);
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    int vsechyZaznamy = mDatabaseHelper.getCountAllLogs();
    int unikatniZaznamy = mDatabaseHelper.getCountUniqueLogs();
    info.setText(vsechyZaznamy+" záznamů, z toho "+unikatniZaznamy+" unikátních.");
    getData();
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getContext();

}
public void getData(){
    List<String> dataZaznamy = mDatabaseHelper.getAllLogs();
    String[] zaznamy = new String[dataZaznamy.size()];
    zaznamy = dataZaznamy.toArray(zaznamy);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(context,zaznamy));
}


}
```

**Adapter.java** of `RecycleView`:

```
package cz.revelio.mhdapp;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    String[] items;
    public Adapter(Context context, String[] items){
        this.context=context;
        this.items=items;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.costume_row, viewGroup, false);
    Item item=new Item(row);
    return item;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    String text = items[position];
    final String casti[] = text.split(",");
    ((Item)viewHolder).itemName.setText(casti[0]);
    ((Item)viewHolder).itemCount.setText(casti[2]+"x");
    ((Item)viewHolder).itemLast.setText("Naposledy zapsáno:  "+casti[3]);
    ((Item) viewHolder).lay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "OnClick Called on position "+position+" a lince "+ casti[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Fragment fragment = new VehicleFragment();
         Bundle b = new Bundle();
         b.putString("vehicle_id", casti[0]);
         fragment.setArguments(b);

         //android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = get
          /*  Intent intent = new Intent(context, VehicleList.class);
            intent.putExtra("vehicle_id", casti[0]);
            context.startActivity(intent);*/
        }
    });
    ((Item) viewHolder).lay.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "OnLongClick Called on position "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.length;
}
public class Item extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView itemName;
    TextView itemCount;
    TextView itemLast;
    ConstraintLayout lay;

    public Item(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        itemName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        itemCount= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_count);
        itemLast= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_last);
        lay = (ConstraintLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_rr);
    }
}


}
```

**VehicleFragment** where is second `RecyclerView` and where I need data from `SeznamFragment.java`:

```
package cz.revelio.mhdapp;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.List;


public class VehicleFragment  extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "LineList";
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    Context context;
    String vehicle_id;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_seznam, container, false);

    }

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getContext();
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    //getIncomingIntent();
}

/*private void getIncomingIntent(){

    if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("vehicle_id")){
        String vehicle_id =  getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("vehicle_id");
        getData(vehicle_id);
    }
}*/

public void getData(String id_vehicle){
    List<String> dataZaznamy = mDatabaseHelper.getAllLogsByVehId(id_vehicle);
    String[] zaznamy = new String[dataZaznamy.size()];
    zaznamy = dataZaznamy.toArray(zaznamy);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new AdapterVehicle(context,zaznamy));
    }

}
```

**AdapterVehicle** of second `RecyclerView`:

```
package cz.revelio.mhdapp;



import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AdapterVehicle extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    Context context;
    String[] items;

    public AdapterVehicle(Context context, String[] items){
        this.context=context;
        this.items=items;

    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.costume_row_veh, viewGroup, false);
        Item item=new Item(row);
        return item;
    }
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    String text = items[position];
    final String casti[] = text.split(",");
    if(casti[5].equals("true")) {
        ((Item) viewHolder).itemName.setText("Jízda linkou " + casti[1]);
    }else{
        ((Item) viewHolder).itemName.setText("Linka " + casti[1]);
    }
    ((Item)viewHolder).itemCount.setText(casti[2]);
    ((Item)viewHolder).itemLast.setText(casti[3]);
    ((Item) viewHolder).lay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Toast.makeText(context, "OnClick Called on position "+position+" a lince "+ casti[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, VehicleEdit.class);
            intent.putExtra("vehicle_id", casti[0]);
            intent.putExtra("line", casti[1]);
            intent.putExtra("datum", casti[2]);
            intent.putExtra("cas", casti[3]);
            intent.putExtra("jedu", casti[5]);
            intent.putExtra("id", casti[4]);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    ((Item) viewHolder).lay.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "OnLongClick Called on position "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //pass the 'context' here
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Smazat záznam");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Chcete záznam smazat?");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ano", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Záznam vozidla "+casti[0]+" na lince "+casti[1]+" byl smazán.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mDatabaseHelper.removeItem(casti[4]);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SeznamFragment.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Ne", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
            dialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.length;
}
public class Item extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView itemName;
    TextView itemCount;
    TextView itemLast;
    ConstraintLayout lay;

    public Item(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        itemName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name_veh);
        itemCount= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_count_veh);
        itemLast= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_last_veh);
            lay = (ConstraintLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_rr_veh);
        }
    }
}
```

I  tried another solutions from StackOvreflow but nothing work for me.

Here you can find my actual codes
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W6OzBCjwH4PJkix73woLCHHDBrh26-U1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

you can pass with Bundle :

```
public static VehicleFragment newInstance(String your_data_if_its_string) {
        VehicleFragment frag = new VehicleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(PersonDBFields.ID, person_id);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }
```

place it in your `VehicleFragment`,
and use `VehicleFragment.newInstance("yourData");` or you can create a field in your class and make a `Setter` for it  , then call `setter` method instead of `Bundle`  inside your new instance.

Comment: Is it able to open layout of VehicleFragment, because now it is called but, i don't know how to display fragment.

Comment: when you call this static method , this will create a fragment object , and you can replace this with your fragment object inside toyr fragmentTransaction , like this :    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()..replace(R.id.mainLayout, VehicleFragment .newInstance("yourdata"), fragment.getClass().getName()).commit();

Comment: ok, i understand how to show fragment, but after create new instance on VehicleFragment in Adapter.java, I can't call method getSupportFragmentManager(). This method is not defined, i probably did something bad, but i don't what.

Comment: if you mean u cant use getSupportFragmentManager() ? you can use ((AppCompatActivity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: I am sorry, I'm begginer and  am little bit lost. I can recapitulated that. I add your code with bundle to VehicleFragment and in Adapter i called VehicleFragment.newInstance("data to pass"); and after that i want show fragment layout. After newInstance i want call getSupportFragmentManager() but in AndroidStudio I have it red. Cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager() is errormessage

Comment: you should cast getSupportFragmentManager() to context which has been casted in app Compat activity , i wrote it for you , --->>>> ((AppCompatActivity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager() , or you can use getFragmentManager() instead of support one.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing everything right except you are not adding it to the fragment manager that's why you are not able to start SecondFragment. Do it like this :

```
    VehicleFragment frag = new VehicleFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(PersonDBFields.ID, person_id);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;

//now add it to the fragment manager.like you are doing in your activity
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, frag).commit();
```

In onCreateView of the new VehicleFragment:

```
//Retrieve the value
String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
```

you have to get the fragment manager inside your adapter class.

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
     VehicleFragment vehicleFragment =VehicleFragment.getInstance();
     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("vehicle_id", casti[0]);
     vehicleFragment.setArguments(b);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();         
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.fragment_container, 
    myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

 }
```

Comment: On this case I have problem with static method. VehicleFragment must be static, but I  called  non-static method getFragmentManager.

Comment: you can use Ali Reza's newInstance method to create new VehicleFragment.

Comment: I used that method, bud when I called getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, frag).commit(); inside that method it waserror with statics method and when iused it in Adapter, it can't resolve getFragmentManager,i'm sorry, im little bit lost in ti

Comment: check the updated onclick method to open new fragment from another

Comment: I tried it,but still wrong. In question you can find file with my actual codes, I hope, that will help to describe me how it works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Android [Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/) has some pretty good libraries that have [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) objects that make it easier to manage and store data.
It lets you access data at different activities or fragments in an application. You try it and hope it will be useful to you